# I want the pattern printing using Javascript

Tags: javascript

For a given number N, print the grid as shown below using JavaScript, where N is a positive 
integer greater than 2.

Example output for N=3

1 1 1

1 0 1

1 1 1

Example output for N=4

1 1 1 1

1 0 0 1

1 0 0 1

1 1 1 1

Comment: And what did you try? We are not a homework answering service.

Comment: I need a cup of coffee, HELP ME!!!

Comment: please first try and if any error then send there

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printMatrix(n) {

  for (var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
  var x = "";
   for (var j = 0; j <n; j++) {
      if (i == 0 || i == (n-1)) {
        x += "1";
      } else {
        if (j == 0 || j == (n-1) ) {
          x +="1";
        } else {
          x += "0";
        }
      }
    }
    $("#result").append(x + "<br>");
  }

}
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#result").empty();
printMatrix($("#index").val());  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='index'>
<input type='button' value='print' id='btn'>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

even if you didn't try anything, there is my working solution :

```
function printMatrix(n) {

  for (var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
  var x = "";
    for (var j = 0; j <n; j++) {
      if (i == 0 || i == (n-1)) {
        x += "1";
      } else {
        if (j == 0 || j == (n-1) ) {
          x +="1";
        } else {
          x += "0";
        }
      }
    }
    $("#result").append(x + "<br>");
  }

}

printMatrix(5);
```

You can improve it easily

Here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dqr3vex/)

Answer (score 0):

Explicit loops are so passé; here's a little something I put together using the [ES6 `Array.prototype.fill()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
let makeSquare = (size, hJoin="", vJoin="\n") => {
  let m = Array(size).fill(0, 1, size-1);
  m[0] = m[size-1] = 1;
  let s = Array(size).fill(m.join(hJoin), 1, size-1);
  s[0] = s[size-1] = Array(size).fill(1).join(hJoin);
  return s.join(vJoin);
};

console.log(makeSquare(5));
console.log(makeSquare(3, " "));
document.body.innerHTML = makeSquare(4, " ", "<br>");
```

Browser support may vary, in the sense that **IE doesn't support `.fill()`**, but there is a [`.fill()` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill)...

Of course you can't polyfill arrow functions and function argument defaults, but you can rewrite them ES5 style if you care about older IE:

```
var makeSquare = function(size, hJoin, vJoin) {
  if (hJoin === undefined) hJoin = "";
  if (vJoin === undefined) vJoin = "\n";
  var m = Array(size).fill(0, 1, size-1);
  m[0] = m[size-1] = 1;
  var s = Array(size).fill(m.join(hJoin), 1, size-1);
  s[0] = s[size-1] = Array(size).fill(1).join(hJoin);
  return s.join(vJoin);
};
```

[Demo with polyfill that works in IE.](https://jsfiddle.net/s9bo5me9/1/)